# How to know when sqs messages are processed in lambda for n number of customers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Lets say there are 10 customers.
Each customers 1000 messages are pushed to sqs. Lambda is consuming the message. How to know when 1000 messages for client a is processed in lambda. we need to send notification as email or websocket to customer.

Answer (score 0):

Architectures using Amazon SQS typically assume that all messages are 'equal'.

There is no way of knowing how many messages with particular attributes are consumed. When counting the Number of Messages in a queue, it simply **counts the entire queue size**.

Your Lambda function would need to **update a database** (eg DynamoDB) to track how many messages for each client have been processed.

Or, you could **use separate queues for each client**.